# Linux сервер, как шлюз по-умолчанию

Tags: centos, virtualbox, шлюз

Здравствуйте. Работаю с VirtualBox, Linux-сервер на CentOS 7, хост - WindowsXP.
Пробую настроить сервер, как шлюз, но не получается сделать доступ в интернет для хоста. Делал по примеру из видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aBTqCBpnf4.
Интернет у меня идет через роутер с интерфейсом 192.168.0.1, этот интерфейс -
 шлюз по-умолчанию для интерфейса на сервере (192.168.0.56), который предназначен для выхода в интернет. Для внутренней сети - интерфейс 192.168.20.1, являющийся шлюзом для хоста - 192.168.20.2. Связь есть, ping проходит с хоста до обоих интерфейсов сервера, но вот в интернет с хоста ping не проходит. Брэндмауэр на хосте отключен.

Answer (score 0):

Окей, у меня не было включено перенаправление пакетов в файл /etc/sysctl.conf нужно добавить:

> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

После этого прописал еще раз зоны для интерфейсов и всё встало.
Получилось благодаря вот этому примеру:
http://blog.redbranch.net/2015/07/30/centos-7-as-nat-gateway-for-private-network/